# 2sxc: Merge more streams in a Default one

Tags: 2sxc

I have an app that can have one or more streams
Example:

> Book of author A 
>   Book of author B
>   Book of author C

So my queries can have one or more relationship filters.
Assuming that I would like to use only one template for more views, and a view can have more streams so I can't have the names of each one in my template, how can i do that?
Basically in my template I would like to have a unique list even if I got more streams

```
AsDynamic(Data["Default"]) //This should get all the streams in my data
```

Is that possible? Maybe aggregating them in Visual query?
I'm trying to have an out stream coming from many but giving the same name I got and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this is not possible (2sxc 8.5.6). There are a few problems related to this idea

1. the same item could occur multiple times, this is not supposed to happen in a stream
2. you will probably loose the "which author was this for" information

As of now, I recommend to either just merge them in js or server-side code if this is what you need.

Comment: Thanks you, my problem ia that I would use only one template cause that should be the same... Anyway I will try an other solution. :)

Comment: please can you have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39977623/2sxc-dropdown-list-get-label-instead-of-value-in-razor-template

Comment: I would like to sort this that is getting me out :)