# 2sxc Content App - Locations - How to convert to Canadian and US Addresses with region/state

Tags: region, 2sxc, dnn9

I am using the latest versions on 2sxc (11.05) and the Content App on DNN 9.06. The Content-Type for Locations does not have a field for Region (or State). Is there already something in place to account for that to get Canadian or US addresses to output normally? I realize I can add the field and then maybe use the Dropdown from Query to hook it up to DNN's list of Regions, and then modify the Views accordingly...

But that seems like a lot of work for something that might already be built in (and I just don't see it?). Or is there another easy way to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

Truth be told - we never needed that so far, so it doesn't exist.

Is this necessary for maps to work, or just another field which a standard us-address needs? I'm curious because neither outlook nor SharePoint seem to require such a field, so I never really thought about it.

BUT: if you do implement it, please do share it back with us, so we can publish it.

Note that if this is important, a possibly nicer solution would be to use a public api somewhere which provides this information, as it's most certainly more complete & up to date for this purpose. If this is the case, ping me and I'll implement a string-dropdown-from-json or something like that :)

Comment: It is just a standard field that various countries need to output a stand formatted address. If you add it, I think the field should be named "Region". Other countries besides the US (States) and Canada (Provinces) expect and use this designation. Also, DNN has built in Lists for both Canada's Provinces and USA's States. I gave an example of accessing them in code in this slightly related question a few days ago
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63906668/how-can-i-output-just-the-text-of-a-select-instead-of-the-value-in-2sxc-razor-te

Comment: There are services like this https://www.zipcodeapi.com/ that let you convert a US zip code in to city/region and more. However, any solution like that will be too USA specific and it seems like you need to remain country-agnostic. Since DNN has the data for US and Canada, and I assume it would stay up to date and ISO friendly, maybe 2sxc could come up with a way to populate a dropdown somehow using DNN's ListController() and settings to get the needed name/value pairs?

Comment: ok, we'll look into this, but it won't have a high priority.